# Получение количества полей таблицы БД.

Tags: delphi, interbase, sql

Господа, просветите, пожалуйста, как в delphi программно получить количество полей определенной таблицы БД? В качестве сервера используется Interbase. Для соединения с бд используется модуль с помещенными на него DQLConnection, SimpleDataSet, SQLQuery, DataSource.

```
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Fields.Clear;
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(Format('select count(*) from NEW_TABLE',[]));
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Open;
string1:=datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Fields[0].Value;
```

Данный код возвращает 0.

Comment: Так значит количество записей в таблице = 0.

Вам что именно надо то? Если список полей то зачем 'count(*)' ?

Comment: Извините, количества полей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Interbase поддерживает INFORMATION_SCHEMA, то так:

```
select COUNT(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'NEW_TABLE'
```

Если нет, то нужно использовать системные таблицы:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME='NEW_TABLE';
```

Comment: Ни первый, ни второй способ не работают. 
В первом случае - на ".Columns"
Во втором случае- на "="

Comment: Это кто ругается? Delphi или Interbase?
У вас с кавычками все нормально при встраивании запроса в код?

Comment: interbase. Да, с кавычками все должно быть нормально. Проверял.

Comment: Второй способ помог. Запрос должен был выглядеть так :
Format('SELECT count(*)FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS WHERE     RDB$RELATION_NAME='+#39+'NEW_TABLE'+#39,[])

Answer (score 0):

а разве вариант:

```
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Fields.Clear;
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(Format('select * from NEW_TABLE limit 1',[]));
datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Open;
string1:=datamodule3.SQLQuery1.Fields.Length;//или Count не помню
```

не работает?

Но правда не уверен что это будет быстрее чем вариант [@msi](/users/2339/msi). Но зато на любой БД должен работать.

Comment: Извините, не работает(
Сначала ругалось на "1" в запросе. Убрал её, после этого возвращает пустое значение.

Comment: А что значит "пустое значение"?
limit 1 можно в принципе убрать, это ограничение на количество возвращаемых записей.